# image, input text next to each other: vertical fail

Tags: html, css

I have this form:

```
<div id="newletter">
<form>
    <img width="94" height="61" alt="newsletter email" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-d0K0OLGJ-sYQr96JWC6Kz38fd8aFnhiIer4B9fpNiPyic_Tw">
    <input type="text" name="Nev" placeholder="Név">
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email cím">
    <input type="submit" value="Feliratkozom">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
 #newletter form {
     text-align: center;
 }
 #newletter img {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 20px;
 }
 #newletter input {
     height: 61px;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 4px;
     color: #434343;
     font-family: rock;
     padding-left: 20px;
     font-size: 0.6em;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 20px;
 }
 #newletter input[type="submit"] {
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     border: none;
     height: 58px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 0px;
 }
 body {
     background-color: red;
 }
```

**Fiddle here :** http://jsfiddle.net/8G2Pw/

as you can see, the image is upper than it should. It should be at the same line as input fields. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `vertical-align:top;` missing from the images.

Images by default take `inline` property...so when you make them `block`....and haven't mentioned their position, they tend to take default vertical align!!

It should be :

```
     #newletter img {
            display: inline-block; /* here you changed the default display type 
of image, so v-alignment is also required if you want a custom alignmnet*/
            margin-right: 20px;
            vertical-align:top; /*added*/
        }
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8G2Pw/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/7hX5C/):

```
 #newletter img
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="newletter">        
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <img width="94" height="61" alt="newsletter email" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-d0K0OLGJ-sYQr96JWC6Kz38fd8aFnhiIer4B9fpNiPyic_Tw">
</td>
<td valign = "bottom">
<input type="text" name="Nev" placeholder="Név"><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email cím"><input type="submit" value="Feliratkozom">
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```